# Employer match after tax?

Tags: united-states, 401k, employer-match

My employer matches 2% of my contributions to my 401k but insists those contributions cannot be pre-tax. Is that correct?

Answer (score 18):

It's the opposite. The match *must* be pretax. If you have a Roth 401(k) for example, the match goes into the traditional side of the 401(k) account, not the Roth.

Comment: +1 Many people seem to exhibit a profound confusion between the notions of pretax and post-tax in the context of 401k contributions.

Comment: is there an IRS source that says employer matches *must* be pre tax? my employer allows me to choose whether employer contributions go in pre-tax or post-tax, and that difference shows up on my paychecks and in my account balances.

Comment: @Ben Look at www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-on-Designated-Roth-Accounts#10 where it says `Yes, your employer can make matching contributions on your designated Roth contributions. .... Your employer must allocate any contributions to match designated Roth contributions into a pre-tax account, just like matching contributions on traditional, pre-tax elective contributions.` What _you_ contribute to your 401k account, asking your employer to send the money directly to the 401k is different from what the employer contributes as the **matching** amount, (continued)

Comment: ... (continuation) and what the employer contributes as the matching amount should have no effect on your take-home pay.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - thanks for the support and IRS citation.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes I'm aware of the difference between *my* contributions and my *employer's* contributions. My paychecks show *all* of my benefits, including those that don't effect my take home pay (that's how my company chooses to display everything), and my paychecks show four things: 1) my traditional 401(K) contributions, 2) my roth 401(K) contributions, 3) my employer's matching contributions to my traditional 401(K), and 4) my employer's matching contributions to my Roth 401(K). I was confused because they break down *their* matching contributions into pre-tax and post-tax.

Comment: I guess my employer erroneously breaks down *their* matching contributions that way, since that document is pretty clear. Once again, I'm *perfectly* clear on the difference between my own contributions and my employer's matching contributions.

Comment: @Ben  Good. The question is **where** does the _employer's_ contribution that matches your Roth 401k contribution go? You seem to be claiming that the matching money becomes part of _your_ Roth 401k, but the IRS say that whatever money your employer contributes a matching contribution to your Roth 401k is not Roth money, it is traditional 401k money and you will be taxed on it when you take a distribution from it. You may well have _four_ 401k accounts listed, your own contribution accounts to Traditional and Roth 401k and your employer matches to these. Only one of these is post-tax Roth.....

Comment: .. your own contributions that you directed to your Roth 401k account: the _employer match_ to _your_ Roth contributions might be broken out separately as a line item on your paystub, but that is _not_ Roth money and it is going into a traditional 401k account, same as the employer match to your traditional 401k contributions.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yep that makes sense now. I guess my confusion came from how my employer annotates stuff on my paycheck, since as you say, only my roth contributions are *actually* roth. Thanks for the info! (and thanks for the IRS link too, that's really helpful). I need to check my balances again and talk to my employer because it's actually pretty ambiguous where their matching contributions go (even though as you clarified, they're definitely pre-tax).